# JqGrid fail to load data with jDialog

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, jqgrid, jdialog

I am using jqGrid to load date from a ColdFusion 9 server. My jQuery version is jquery-1.9.1.

The return format is JSON, and I am using 6 jqGrids on 6 different pages. Plus I have a dialog pop-up on each page.

My problem is that when navigate between grids, and open pop-ups, multiple times
the grid stops loading any data and shows white space instead of columns! I have to refresh the browser in order to make it work.

I have searched a lot but with no result. How can I fix this issue?

This is how I call each grid:

```
$("#DRIVERNNPN_InquiryGrid_similar").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",mtype: "POST",position:"center",closeOnEscape: false,
    colNames: [ NAME,DLN, DLDATE,NATIONAL_NUM,MOBILE],
    colModel: [
        { name: "NAME", width: 150 , align: "center", sortable:true},               
        { name: "DLN", width: 150 , align: "center", sortable:true},
        { name: "DLDATE", width: 150 , align: "center", sortable:true},
        { name: "NATIONAL_NUM", width: 150 , align: "center", sortable:true},
        { name: "MOBILE", width: 350 , align: "center" , sortable:true},
        //{ name: "ACTIONLINK", width: 25 , align: "center" , sortable:false, formatter: "image"},              
    ],
    pager: "#pager2",refresh:false,rowNum: 5,sortname: "capacity",sortorder: "asc", 
    loadComplete: function(data) {
        showLoadingMsg(false);
    },
    viewrecords: true,gridview: true,scrollOffset: 0,autoencode: true,direction: "rtl", altRows:false,height: "200px",
    postData: {},       
    jsonReader: {
        root: "ROWS", page: "PAGE",total: "TOTAL",records:"RECORDS",userdata:"USERDATA",cell: "",id: "0"
    } 
});
```

and this is how I open the pop-up:

```
$(function() {   
$( "#dialog-SearchBlacklist" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 180,
  width: 320,
  modal: true,
  close: function() {
     $( this ).dialog( "close" );
     $(document).unbind();
     $(':input').each(function() {
     this.value = "";
 });
  },
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 250
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "fold",
    duration: 250
 }
```

});

and here is the part from the coldfusion side:

```
<cffunction name="inquiryTN" access="remote" returnFormat="json" securejson="no">
<cfquery name="qry_TNPermits">
    select PN,TN,statuscode from Trucks
</cfquery>

<cfset userdata = {type="Error",msg="Error"}>
<!--- Get JSON Format for the grid from a private function --->
<cfset strReturn = getGridJSONFormat(Arguments.page,Arguments.rows,qry_TNPermits,
                    'PN,TN,statuscode',userdata)>       
<cfreturn strReturn>
```

and

```
<cffunction name="getGridJSONFormat" access="public" retunformat="json">
<cfargument name="page" type="numeric" required="no" default="1">
<cfargument name="rows" type="numeric" required="no" default="10">
<cfargument name="qryRecords" type="query" required="yes">
<cfargument name="COLUMNLIST" type="string" required="yes">
<cfargument name="userdata" required="no" default="">

<cfset var arrRecords = ArrayNew(1)>
<cfset var start = 0>
<cfset var end = 0>
<cfset var totalPages = 0>      
<cfset var i = 1>
<cfset strReturn = "">      

<cfset start = ((arguments.page-1)*arguments.rows)+1>
<cfset end = (start-1) + arguments.rows>

 <cfloop query="qryRecords" startrow="#start#" endrow="#end#">
     <cfset var temp = arrayNew(1)>             
     <cfloop array="#ListToArray(arguments.columnList)#" index="col">
     <cftry>
         <cfset var tempVar= qryRecords[col]>
     <cfcatch type="any">
        <cfset var tempVar= ''>
     </cfcatch>
     </cftry>   

        <cfset ArrayAppend(temp ,tempVar)>              
     </cfloop>  
     <cfset arrRecords[i] = temp> 
     <cfset ArrayClear(temp)>
     <cfset i = i + 1> 
</cfloop>

<cfset totalPages = Ceiling(qryRecords.recordcount/arguments.rows)>

<!--- The JSON return --->
<cfset strReturn = {total=#totalPages#,page=#Arguments.page#,records=#qryRecords.recordcount#,rows=arrRecords,userdata=#userdata#}>          
<cfreturn strReturn>
```

Comment: Do you have ColdFusion's Robust Exception Reporting turned on in CF Administrator?  Take a closer look at the JSON response in your browser's developer tools or using a tool like Charles or Fiddler.  You may have a ColdFusion error in your server-side code.  These often are displayed with a bunch of whitespace ahead of the actual error information.

Comment: Thank you for you response, but I dont think this is the problem, because the response is returned with no error, but nothing is displayed... and as I said in my question, the first few times I request the grid, it shows the data with no problem.. the problem occurs when I request the grid for multiple times.... I use Firebug to view the response, and yes my ColdFusion's Robust Exception is activated.

Comment: Try turning off the Robust Exception Handling. This should be off in 99.99% of production servers anyway for performance and security reasons.

Also, in looking at your code more closely, where is ColdFusion even involved? Your grids are populated from JavaScript data (see the `datatype: "local"` part of the first code snippet). This seems to really be an issue with jqGrid and jQuery dialog only.

Comment: first of all, right now I am still on development server, not productions...so my robust exceptions is still active.
about datatype="local", i use this to prevent the grid from bind on load, then I use....

datatype:'JSON',
url: "entities/inquiry/cfc/InquiryFactoryWEB.cfc?method=inquiry"+x,

I am still having the problem, any other suggestion?

Comment: That would have been useful to know from the outset. Very little of the code you posted is really relevant to the problem then - you need to show the code that is *actually* returning the JSON response.

Comment: I have updated my original post with the ColdFusion code

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong with that code.  My only suggestions would be that you don't need all the pound signs ("#") in the `<cfset>` statement building the strReturn variable, and that you should var the initial `<cfset strReturn = "">` near the top of the function.

Comment: I just noticed that both functions are returning JSON.  Which may result in the JSON being double encoded and that could be a problem.  Try removing the `returnformat="json"` from the getGridJSONFormat() function.  Let the main inquiryTN() function take care of the JSON encoding.